# Implementing own application repository and/or package manager for android?

Tags: android, software-distribution

Is there away to implement own application repository and package manager/downloader for android device? A repository that would be located on local the server, and package manager that might make download/install decisions differently from default Play App.

Keeping repository on local server would ensure that only authorized applications can be downloaded to device on the local network.

What would be involved for this (both from android device and back-end server that would provide applications to device)?

---

One alternative repository/downloader that I tried on android is F-Droid. I am thinking of something along those lines.. except that I am not sure what would I need on server side for this to happen.

Also.. For first step, I primary interested for testing purposes. Or for a very small group like school / or small company.

Comment: A whole heckuva lot more than a simple answer anyone here can give you.

Comment: Well.. yea.... But at least direction or how possible it is under default rooted android.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but at the very least you can publish all of your apks to Artifactory (super easy if you are using gradle for your builds) which you host on the local network. Then using the restful api of Artifactory, you can create a mobile web front end that will allow you to view/download any of the apks that are in our artifactory repository.  That is something that you should be able to set up in the matter of days.

Comment: I think a bigger issue is how to get people to tell their device that the repository is "trusted".  I think that depends on the menufacturer.  Mine only trusts Play.  Kindles only trust Amazon.  And I don't know that you can change that.  In other words, even if you could change that, how would you get your users to go along with it?

Comment: Well.. I primary interested for testing purposes at first. Or for a very small group like school / or small company.

Comment: right, we did this for enterprise deployment to internal users. It ended up being substantially easier to have a website where users can update than having to email the new apks everytime it came out.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special or complicated about hosting a repository, it would be just like any other web server.  You just store APK files and distribute them using APK mimetype.  Also you'd need a database backend to store device/app combinations.

You just need to consider that this won't be a trusted location to install from, so all your users need to enable "allow 3rd party apps" or whatever their OEM calls that setting on their device.

Also, I don't know why you'd want a custom package manager/installer, what extra functionality are you looking for?